# Why does Polymer cli element has service worker error on demo page?

Tags: polymer, polymer-cli

When I use the polymer cli v. `0.17.0` and run `polymer init` then select element it creates a simple element project. 
Then I use `polymer serve` to view the project in a browser.

Why does it start with service worker errors when I navigate to the demo page?

```
A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.  :8080/service-worker.js:1 

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE  http://localhost:8080/service-worker.js
```

Comment: check the path of that file "service-worker.js" where you are serving from. Or maybe its residue of another project that also was localhost:8080 and that also had a service worker in it.

Comment: @RobertRowntree the directory is empty when i generate the element project.  I notice this file exists in an cli generated app project but not a cli generated element project.